# why does the variable keep changing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, loops, expo

Every time I run the nextQuestion, the questions change. it's like running the whole function again, but the nextIndex is not reset.I understand this because I see the category appear several times

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useLocalSearchParams } from "expo-router";
import { COLORS } from "../constants";
import { View, Text, Image, Button, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView } from "react-native";
import { requestQuestions } from "../constants/support";
import Header from '../constants/testHeader';


const Test = () => {
    const { category } = useLocalSearchParams();
    let questions = requestQuestions(category);
    const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(0);
    console.log(category)

    const nextQuestion = () => {
        const nextIndex = (currentQuestion + 1) % questions.length;

        if (nextIndex === 0) {
            alert('All question are finished.');
        } else {
            setCurrentQuestion(nextIndex);
        }
    };

    const { id, img, question, anwsers } = questions[currentQuestion];
    console.log(questions.map(obj => Object.values(obj)[0]), currentQuestion)
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.area}>
            <Image source={img || { uri: "https://www.liaros-drive.gr/test/images/pic0484.jpg" }} style={styles.image} />
            <Text style={styles.title}>{question}</Text>
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                {
                    anwsers && anwsers.map((anwser, index) => (
                        <Button key={index} title={`${index+1}) (${anwser})`} onPress={nextQuestion} />
                    ))
                }
            </SafeAreaView>
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}

export default Test;
```

support.js
the questions it is a array of objects.

```js
import { sampleSize } from 'lodash';
import { questions } from './questions.json';
export const requestQuestions = (category = "random") = \ > {
    console.log('test')
    if (category == "random") {
        return sampleSize(questions, 10)
    } else {
        return sampleSize(questions.filter(x = \ > x.category == category), 10)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call a setter of a state property inside a React component, the  component function is called again - in this case calling `requestQuestions` again, yielding a new list of questions.

Solution: pass the questions as a prop to `Test` to keep them the same:

```
function Test({ questions }) {
  const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(0);
  // ...rest of your component
}
```

and in the parent component:

```
const { category } = useLocalSearchParams();
const questions = requestQuestions(category);

... 

return (
  ...
  <Test questions={questions}/>
  ...
)
```